# Django: Time Zone Issue When Displaying Only Today's Entries

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to grab all of today's entries and then display it to that user based on his or her time zone.  They are stored via a datetime field.  The Issue I have is all times are stored in GMT, so when I pull today's records, they cross over in terms of date, so some entries may be July 3rd, and some entries may be July 4th.  Then when Its displayed to the user via the time zone tags and what not (say Eastern Time), the user will be shown yesterdays entries as well as today's.  I's there any tag or different approach I could use to fix this issue.

Views.py

```
 def get_entry(request):
    start_date = timezone.now().date()
    end_date = start_date + timedelta( days=1 )
    todays_entry = game.objects.filter(date__range=(start_date,end_date)).order_by('date').all()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'todays_entry':todays_entry})
```

Template.py

```
 {% load tz %}
 {% localtime on %}
   {% for x in todays_entry %}
      {{x.date}}.........
   {% endfor %}
 {% endlocaltime %}
```

output would be something like

```
July 3, 2015, 8:05 p.m, 
July 3, 2015, 9:05 p.m, 
July 4, 2015, 1:05 p.m, 
July 4, 2015, 1:05 p.m
```

Where as all I really want is the today's stuff only...

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
def get_entry(request):
   today = datetime.datetime.now().today()
   todays_entry = game.objects.filter(date__year=today.year, date__month=today.month, date__day=today.day)
   return render(request, 'home.html', {'todays_entry':todays_entry})
```

you dont need `.all()` after filter

Comment: todays_entry returns empty when I do it like that.  Date entries are stored like this: 2015-07-01 02:05:00+00:00